# What is the alternative to navigator.msSaveBlob in MS Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Looking at this answer over here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59354688

It claims that navigator.msSaveBlob exists in Edge but when I tried it in the console I got that it was undefined. Is there an alternative to it? This is in Chromium Edge by the way.

Comment: Chromium Edge or the old one?

Comment: @DanielA.White Chromium Edge.